# Ubuntu 12.10 Skype webcam microphone not working

Tags: 12.10, skype, webcam, microphone

This is making me crazy.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, Skype 4.1.0.20 can't use my web cam microphone anymore.

- I can record correctly from the web cam microphone using the sound recorder
- the web cam microphone is selected in the global sound settings and working in any other application.
- Also tried to start skype with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype` and `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so /usr/bin/skype`

No matter what, Skype will keep using the front panel microphone for audio capture. Mic was working fine with Ubuntu 12.04 before I upgraded to 12.10.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solved with pavucontrol. I had already tried the pulseaudio volume control, but you need to do a particular thing to make it work.

First, install pavucontrol:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Then start it:

```
pavucontrol
```

You'll get the volume control window. Now, you could go to "Input devices" and select the webcam microphone as your input source: THIS WON'T WORK. This is how you do have to it:

- Click on the "Recording" tab. This tab shows the applications that are capturing audio in that very moment, so it will probably be empty.
- Start skype then call the Echo / Sound Test Service (or anyone you like who will answer)
- When the other party answers, Skype begins capturing audio and will be shown in the "Recording" tab of the pulseaudio volume control window
- From the "Input from" drop down list, select your webcam

And voilà, you'll get your microphone back.

Alternatively, as described in [SkypeTroubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SkypeTroubleshooting#Selecting%20Microphone%20%28input%20device%29)

- [..] go into the Skype Options menu - Sound Devices
- remove the tick at: Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels.
- Click Apply.
- Readjust the sound mixer controls (pavucontrol input devices will work now).

This worked fine for me.

Comment: for me, unmuting the microphone was enough (under the 3rd tab)

Comment: @f.cipriani thanks for the solution .. it worked for me .. but when i logout/restart, the changes revert .. is there a way to make this permanent?

Comment: Works now on Xubuntu LTS 14.04.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently skype is changing the input device when starting a call... but with pavucontrol it is possible to switch back directly.