# Microphone not working in skype

Tags: sound, skype, microphone

I have installed skype, but I cannot make it work with my headset (corsair vengeance 1500.
The problem is that whichever option I choose as microphone it will never work, and only when I select some options can I hear any sound from skype. My sound does however work for the system sounds and the voice recorder works also.
I cannot enclose a picture of the options I recieve, because neither prnt screen nor shutter allows me to capture the window. 
I have already tried a lot of fixes like checking pavucontrol; it only states that nothing is recording audio even when I´m using the voice recorder.
The options I recieve in the sound options do not show up in skype so I can´t use those options as a guideline.

Comment: What computer do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions that have been proposed and worked for others are:

1. Change the Device Input values under `gstreamer-properties`.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-media

   gstreamer-properties
   ```

   Then adjust the "Plugin" to ALSA and the "Device" to an Analog device.
   (Images at: [Credit to @Gaurav_Java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404234/sound-problem-in-skype-4-2-in-ubuntu-13-10?rq=1)
2. Others found solutions with `pavucontrol`.

   First, install pavucontrol:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
   ```

   Then start it:

   ```
   pavucontrol
   ```

Go to "Input devices" and select the microphone as your input source: THIS WON'T WORK. This is how you do have to it:

Click on the "Recording" tab, showing applications capturing audio that moment (it will probably be empty).

Start Skype

Call the Sound Test

When answered, Skype begins capturing audio and will be shown in the "Recording" tab of the pulseaudio volume control window

Select "Input from" drop down list, select your microphone

(Credit to @f.cipriani [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222765/ubuntu-12-10-skype-webcam-microphone-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 16.04 I found this solution worked:

Simply open Terminal and type `alsamixer` and use the arrow keys on your keyboard to make adjustments to the mic settings.