# Sound problem in skype 4.2 in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, microphone

From RhythmBox, i have confirmed that sound output device is working fine, internal mic/external mic are working as per movement of bar in Input device section of PulseAudio.

However, when I start Skype 4.2 in 64 bit Ubuntu 13.10, neither i/p nor o/p sound devices appear to be working. PulseAudio (Local server ) is enabled under Skype audio settings.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

P.S. While answering the question, please keep in mind that I am a novice.

Answer (score 1):

Changing Device Input values under gstreamer-properties fixed it for me

[Find here](http://solancer.blogspot.in/2012/10/mic-not-working-in-ubuntu-1204-solved.html)

[image]

Answer Credit to @srinivas-gowda

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be found on the link below..

http://linuxg.net/how-to-fix-the-sky...cy-salamander/

Reproducing here for convenience.

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype %U/' /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

Comment: Above link is banned, try this one: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html